# Angular2 obtaining bearer-token web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angular, typescript

I am using asp.net web api and want to authenticate a user using the bearer token.

in my login page I submit the user and call my comunication service

```
   submitLogin():void{
   this.user = this.loginForm.value;
   this._commServe.login(this.user).subscribe(() => {
    this.successMessage = "logged in";
  },
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
  )

}
```

and this is the login

```
   login(user: User) {
   var headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
   headers.append( 'grant_type', 'password');
   var body = JSON.stringify(user);
   return this.http.post(baseUrl + "MeetingSchedulingService/Token"
  , body, { headers: headers })
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I get the good old `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` even though I did enable cors on the service.

How can I fix the above code accordingly.

Kind regards

Comment: This seems like a CORS issue more than token related. Post your back end code.

Comment: Issue was resolved thanks. It gave me a 400 which points to a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem. I used a jwt with angular2 and get the token from my WS when the login was OK. Then, all request contains the user token.
Maybe you have to define in your webservice that the route '/auth' does not require the `Authorization: Bearer` header.